# Getting Camera error in Zxing Barcode Application

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode-scanner, zxing

I am trying to use Zxing Library for developing a barcode scanner.

My activity is as follows:

```
public class Scanner extends Activity {  

    private static final String PACKAGE = "com.test.scan";  
    private static final String SCANNER = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";  
    private static final String SCAN_FORMATS = "UPC_A,UPC_E,EAN_8,EAN_13,CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128";  
    private static final String SCAN_MODE = "QR_CODE_MODE";  
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;  

    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {  
        super.onCreate(icicle);  

        setContentView(R.layout.main);  

         Button ok;  
         ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);  
         ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  

             public void onClick(View v) {  

                Intent scanIntent = new Intent(SCANNER);  
                scanIntent.setPackage(PACKAGE);  
                scanIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);  
                scanIntent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", SCAN_FORMATS);  
                scanIntent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", SCAN_MODE);  
                try {  
                    startActivityForResult(scanIntent, REQUEST_CODE);  
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {  
                     // TODO: Exception handling  
                }  
            }  

        });  
     }
```

Also manifest file:

```
    <activity android:name=".Scanner"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">  
                 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
            </intent-filter>

</activity>

<activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action     android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />
                    <category    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.PreferencesActivity"
                android:label="@string/preferences_name">
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.HelpActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="user">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.share.ShareActivity"
                android:label="@string/share_name" android:screenOrientation="user"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SHARE" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
```

But I am getting the following error:

"Sorry, the Android camera encountered a problem. You may need to restart the device".

I have followed few blogs.

Log:

```
   Unexpected error initializating camera  
    01-27 10:40:48.281: WARN/CaptureActivity(1007): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service  
    01-27 10:40:48.281: WARN/CaptureActivity(1007):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)  
    01-27 10:40:48.281: WARN/CaptureActivity(1007):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:185)  
    01-27 10:40:48.281: WARN/CaptureActivity(1007):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:165)
   01-27 10:40:48.281: WARN/CaptureActivity(1007):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraManager.openDriver(CameraManager.java:126)
    01-27 10:40:48.281: WARN/CaptureActivity(1007):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.initCamera(CaptureActivity.java:606)  
    01-27 10:40:48.281: WARN/CaptureActivity(1007):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.surfaceCreated(CaptureActivity.java:346)   
    01-27 10:40:48.281: WARN/CaptureActivity(1007):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:532)  
    01-27 10:40:48.281: WARN/CaptureActivity(1007):     at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:339)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means the device returned `null` from `Camera.open()` and it shouldn't ever do that. It's treated as a device bug. I am not sure how you would debug why it is doing this, but that's the cause.

The only time I have seen this happen consistently is on Android 2.2 devices that have a front camera, only. The API for accessing a front camera only appeared in Android 2.3, and the previous `Camera.open()` API method may only return a rear-facing camera. So these return `null`. And it is a device bug, really, since they really need to be running Android 2.3 to let apps use a front camera.

Comment: Yes, it supports 1.5 even. 4.0 will requires 2.1.

Comment: @SeanOwen in my case I have a Samsung Galaxy S (Android 2.3.6) which has a front and rear camera and I get this warning when I try go use the barcode scanner. Is there a way around it? I'm using the latest version of BarcodeScanner. Downloaded it 2 days ago. Thank you.

Comment: It can't make the firmware behave, no. If it returns null it returns null. It's not a function of the app.

Comment: @ConnectinglifewithAndroid did you solved this issue. Im also getting this while using the front camera

Comment: Here the issue was the place of camera permission.there can be many reason. you can find it by your own.also ensure that its not device bug.

Comment: No, that's not correct. Without permission, you get a different failure.

Comment: I m having same issue like this"https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=1648"
Error occur when i try to scan 5th time.
Any one got the solution for this bug please share with all.
I m getting this error in samsung tab pro 12.2

Comment: @SeanOwen I guess somehow you are blocking the camera of the device(see if is possible to release it) because other apps(e.g. Camera app) are also unable to access the camera after this error occurs. I can't use the app anymore if I don't "force close" it. If I close my app the problem disappears. So, I'm pretty sure is a function of your app. I'm using Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.4 Cheers!

Comment: No, definitely not. See the source code and onPause() method. Why would you assume it is not a driver bug? Apps can't disable the camera even if they wanted to.

Answer (score 37):

For Android 6+, because of the "permission" issue, If you got the message "Sorry, the camera encountered a problem. You may need to restart the device.", go to Settings - Apps - find "your app name" - select Permissions and switch on "Camera".

Comment: This unstuck me, thanks! But what is "the permission issue"?

Comment: Apps designed for Android 6.0 will now ask for a permission when they need it. For example, instead of giving an app access to your camera when you install it, you’ll be prompted the first time the app wants to access your camera.

Comment: This is only true if the app targets Android 6+.

Answer (score 16):

permission of camera

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
```

is not at proper place. it should be after application tag.

Comment: do you have sd card in your phone? have you tried the same code on any other device?

Comment: yes. I have sdcard in my device. i tried in galaxy tab as well

Comment: see the link: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/imhotep/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java.htm you are getting error in initCamera() method. try to find out the reason.

Comment: yes.. but i am not getting what is the problem. Let me check it out

Comment: the order of permission is correct? after </application> you should provide permission.

Comment: yep. that solved the problem. Sorry for not noticing and thank you for the solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem.
    While testing on Android M,the camera requires **runtime permission**. Adding this answer just for reference so as to help anyone who is stuck in a similar scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue on Android 8.1.0 with requesting permissions for the app via code.

The reason for that is (I think) due to changed policies in handling device access in newer Android versions you have to ask for permissions in your code. It is not enough to put the needed permissions in your XML. The user has to have the choice of denying access while using the app.

To activate the "give-permission-popup" you can use the following e.g. inside of onCreate of your MainActivity:

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

It should have the same effect like activating permission via settings. But in an actual app, asking for permissions from inside of your app is probably more user friendly.

Answer (score 2):

Just Add camera permission with Toast :

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
              == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
          // Permission is already available, start camera preview
          Toast.makeText(this,"camera permission granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


      } else {
          // Permission is missing and must be requested.
          requestCameraPermission();
      }
```

and :

```
private void requestCameraPermission() {
        // Permission has not been granted and must be requested.
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            // Provide an additional rationale to the user if the permission was not granted
            // and the user would benefit from additional context for the use of the permission.
            // Display a SnackBar with cda button to request the missing permission.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera access is required to Scan The Barcode.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    // Request the permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CaptureActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA);



        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "<b>Camera could not be opened.</b>\\nThis occurs when the camera is not available (for example it is already in use) or if the system has denied access (for example when camera access has been disabled).", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Request the permission. The result will be received in onRequestPermissionResult().
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you have a Device Administrator disabling access to the camera. Should check if the android camera app can start up or if it complains of a device admin.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem
Fixed it with

```
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

Note: this seems to be a recent issue with the OS ( pre V3.0 Android) as the code was previously working.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to sort the issue out by simply placing the camera permissions in the main application.

Answer (score -2):

If you are invoking camera  in android emulator for Android 2.2 it will give exception . While it runs fine on a device.

Answer (score -2):

Check out your code, I think your code trying to open camera multiple times.
Download google zxing barcode scanner source code and then try it.